# iOS app extension enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I would like streamline the process of testing my iOS iMessage extension by automating and distributing builds signed with an enterprise provisioning profile through something like Jenkins.

However after repeated attempts I have found that installing an IPA that includes the app extension does not install the app extension.

I realize as per Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW11) "To deliver an iOS app extension, you must submit a containing app to the App Store."

Despite this, the wording is sufficiently vague enough for me to wonder if there is at all any way to distribute archives that install the messages extension when installed.

1. Has anyone had any success doing this?
2. If not is it because it's actually impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Distributing the containing app via an IPA works perfectly fine.
When the containing app is installed the app extension is also installed as per Apple's documentation.

However for iMessage extensions make sure to check the "managed" tab of the app store to make sure that the extension is added to the iMessage app drawer when it is installed. I missed this originally, hence the original question :(.

Comment: What if the Sticker Pack is a standalone pack?